# How can I pass a variable in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

I want to make my portfolio in Jekyll and I have 4 projects I want to show on frontpage. Each one of them has one unique color (ex. #555, #000, #fff, etc.). Where can I create this variable for each post so I can use this color on frontpage as `<div style="background: {{ post.color }};">`

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable in post/page font matter.
Do not set the hex color value but a class name.

```
---
 title: my title
 layout: mylayout
 class: pageClass1
---
```

This class can then be applied in the `mylayout` :

```
<div class="{{ page.class }}">
```

Then set the style in your css/scss file :

```
.pageClass1{
  backgroud: red;
  color: white;
  .... any other rule for this class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define any such global variable in `_config.yml` and can easily access like `{{site.postColor}}`